# Run latexmk with luatex or pdflatex depending on the local variable

Tags: auctex

I want to run Latexmk automatically with the correct TeX-engine as set in the local file variable at the end of the file, for example:

```
%% Local Variables:
%% TeX-engine: luatex
%% End:
```

In my `.emacs` file I tried something like:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push 
    '("Latexmk" "latexmk %(-PDF) %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run Latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)

'("%(-PDF)"
  (lambda ()
    (if (equal TeX-engine 'luatex)
        "-lualatex" "-pdf"))))
```

but it doesn't work.

So how can I get the desired result?

Comment: I don't know, but could you clean up the code you posted, so it at least has balancing parentheses and is properly indented? As you posted it, your intention is quite unclear. (Hint: Edit the code in an elisp buffer, perhaps `*scratch*`.  Place the cursor at the start and hit `M-C-q` to indent the code. Select the whole block and indent it four spaces with `C-u C-x TAB`. Then paste it into your question.)

Comment: Oh, addendum: After indenting the code in emacs and before copying it, select it again and run `M-x untabify`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going out on a limb and guessing that what you want is more along these lines (*totally untested*):

```
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (push '("Latexmk" "latexmk %(-PDF) %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
             :help "Run Latexmk on file")
           TeX-command-list)
     (push '("%(-PDF)"
             (lambda ()
               (if (equal TeX-engine 'luatex)
                   "-lualatex" "-pdf")))
           TeX-expand-list)))
```

By using `eval-after-load` instead of a hook variable, I avoid having the same value pushed over and over again each time the mode is run. (You could achieve the same by using `pushnew`, since we are trying to push literally the same object on each run. Or by arraning for a hook function to remove itself after running.)